# How can I remove a portion of text from a string whenever it starts with &*( and ends with )(*

Tags: java, regex

I have a long string. Somewhere in the string there is a part of it that starts with `&*(` and then there is some text and it ends with `)(*`.

How can I remove this text along with the special symbols in the beginning and in the end?

Example:

```
Bla bla bla &*( asd asd asd )(* bla bla bla. Yadda yadda yadda &*( akls lkja )(* yadda.
```

I want to output

```
Bla bla bla bla bla bla. Yadda yadda yadda  yadda.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.replaceAll()`:

```
String replaced = "Bla bla bla &*( asd asd asd )(* bla bla bla. Yadda yadda yadda &*( akls lkja )(* yadda."
                      .replaceAll("\\Q&*(\\E.+?\\Q)(*\\E", "");
```

Here is an [online code demo](http://ideone.com/XLfSrN)!

This is the regular expression:

```
\Q&*(\E.+?\Q)(*\E
```

- `\Q` Start quoting literal sequence.
- - `&*(` Literal character sequence **"&*("**.
- `\E` End
- `.+?` Matches more than one characters, as few as possible (lazy)
- `\Q` Start quoting literal sequence.
- - `)(*` Literal character sequence **")(*"**.
- `\E` End

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/yJ6mN7/1)!

Answer (score 4):

use `replaceAll` To do this:

```
    String s ="Bla bla bla &*( asd asd asd )(* bla bla bla. Yadda yadda yadda &*( akls lkja )(* yadda.Bla bla bla &*( asd asd asd )(* bla bla bla. Yadda yadda yadda &*( akls lkja )(* yadda.";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\&\\*\\(.+?\\)\\(\\*", ""));
```

Comment: Can you walk me through that regex pattern?

Comment: @BheshGurung You are right. I have removed the grouping

Comment: @JK It matches the eye catcher `&*(` then all character (.+) until the next combination of `)(*`

Answer (score 0):

For String manipulation I would recommend the use of StringBuilder.
StringBuilder is mutable and does not create a new string for each operation

You can try the following:

```
final String START_INDEX = "&*(";
final String END_INDEX = ")(*";
String str = "Bla bla bla &*( asd asd asd )(* bla bla bla. Yadda yadda yadda &*( akls lkja )(* yadda.";

StringBuilder sbuild = new StringBuilder(str);
for(int start = sbuild.indexOf(START_INDEX); start != -1;){
    int end = sbuild.indexOf(END_INDEX);
    sbuild.replace(start, end + END_INDEX.length(), "");
    start = sbuild.indexOf(START_INDEX);
}

System.out.println(sbuild.toString());
```

Comment: Two notices: 1. `StringBuilder` IS mutable, it stores the added content as characters, that's why its recomended for string concatenation. 2. What if the string doesn't contain `"&*("`? Then nothing gets added to the `sbuild`.

Comment: 1. Correct it is mutable. this is what I wanted to write. I will edit my answer.    2. I understood that we always have "&*(". If this is not the case you can easily fix the code I wrote in my answer.