# How do I remove multiple occurrences of a pattern from a string in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am interested in removing all occurrences of a pattern in a Python string where the pattern looks like "`start-string` blah, blah, blah `end-string`". This is a general problem I'd like to be able to handle. This is the same problem as [How can I remove a portion of text from a string whenever it starts with &*( and ends with )(*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25347010/how-can-i-remove-a-portion-of-text-from-a-string-whenever-it-starts-with-and) but in Python and not Java.

How would I solve the same problem in Python?

Assume the string looks like this,

```
'Bla bla bla <mark asd asd asd /> bla bla bla. Yadda yadda yadda <mark alls lkja /> yadda.'
```

The start of the block to remove is `<mark` and the end is `/>`. So I do the following:

```
import re
mystring = "Bla bla bla <mark asd asd asd /> bla bla bla. Yadda yadda yadda <mark akls lkja /> yadda."
tags = "<mark", "/>"
re.sub('%s.*%s' % tags, '', mystring)
```

My desired output is

```
'Bla bla bla  bla bla bla. Yadda yadda yadda  yadda.'
```

But what I get is

```
'Bla bla bla  yadda.'
```

So clearly the command is using the first instance of the opening string and the last occurrence of the end string.

How do I make it match the pattern twice and give me the desired output? This has to be easy but despite searches on "remove multiple occurrences regex Python" and the like I have not found an answer. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python non-greedy regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766372/python-non-greedy-regexes)

Comment: @Robin: I agree. I actually got the definition of greedy backwards. Live and learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically want to find anything between `'<mark'` and '`/>'` so you start with the pattern

```
r'<mark .* />'
```

However the `.*` will be greedy, so to make it non-greedy you need to add a `?`, then simply use `re.sub` to replace those matches with empty string

```
>>> re.sub(r'<mark .*? />', '', s)
'Bla bla bla  bla bla bla. Yadda yadda yadda  yadda.'
```